# .htaccess for routing Single Page Applications

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, routes

I am developing a single page application where I pushing various module loads to the URL as path. We have inbuilt handler to change the path to parameters internally.

But to make it bookmarkable we have to use `.htaccess` to manage the paths.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^applications/sample([/]+[a-z]+)+$ applications/sample/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now this is working till the first level....

`applications/sample/module` is loading fine.... but

`applications/sample/module/submodule` is not working...

Where am I going wrong with the RewriteRule ? I am looking for the following rule....

```
<rule>
  <note>Rewrite sample/module1, sample/module2, ... sample/moduleX to /sample/index.html and sub-modules as well</note>
  <from>/sample/(home|book|table|...|module)(.*)</from>
  <to>/sample/index.html</to>
</rule>
```

Comment: Describe "not working". Your regex is not optimal (it allows multiple slashes for instance), however, it should match the URLs given. Maybe there is something different with your "real" URLs?

Comment: @w3dk I have updated the question if that helps... Not working means the index.html seems to loading since there is no server error... but the js, css files etc are getting 404

Comment: So, the code you have posted "is working", but you are not getting the desired results. It sounds as if you are using relative URLs to your JS/CSS resources? Where are these resources located? Are they also getting rewritten?

Comment: for the first path its working sample/module ... but for sample/module/sub-module its not working... the css js file are throwing 404

Answer (score 1):

> for the first path its working `sample/module` ... but for `sample/module/sub-module` its not working... the css js file are throwing 404

This can happen if you are using relative URLs to your external resources (JS, CSS and images) in your client-side HTML. Since the 2nd URL is effectively in a (virtual) "subdirectory", any relative client-side URLs are relative to that "subdirectory", not the parent directory, as it is with the first URL.

See my answer on Pro Webmasters for more detail:
[.htaccess rewrite url leads to missing css](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243)

---

If instead, the linked external resources (ie. JS and CSS files) are being rewritten then you can prevent this by adding some conditions/exceptions. To exclude rewritting when accessing static resources (physical files on the filesystem):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^applications/sample(/[a-z]+)+$ applications/sample/index.html [L]
```

I also tweaked the `RewriteRule` regex to prevent multiple slashes being accepted. (I assume you don't need to catch multiple slashes?)

Comment: No, the issue is not with the js, css I guess. The path is not getting selected fully by the regex in `.htaccess` . Its passing only `sub-module` to  index.html while it should pass `module/sub-module`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If the JS and CSS files (static resources) are being rewritten as well, then they can be omitted by only rewritting URLs that don't map to filesystem resources. I've updated my answer.

Comment: The .htaccess directive is not "passing" anything. You said in comments that "index.html seems to [be] loading since there is no server error" - so the rewrite is working as intended. The rest is then up to your "inbuilt handler to change the path to parameters internally". What is the URL in your HTML for your JS and CSS files? What JS and CSS URLs are being requested that generate the 404?