# Is there a way to rewrite all url's in .htaccess to index.html but existing folders? as I use Vue-Router

Tags: vue.js, apache, .htaccess, vuejs3, vue-cli

I built a `VUE CLI` Web App Containing `Vue-Router` and so I should rewrite all requests to `index.html` file like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.html [L]
```

But there is a problem that there are two folders `css` and `js` containing packed `css`'s and `js`'s, automaticly generated by `Vue-CLI`. And the browser will send a request like: `https://example.com/css/xyz.css` but as rewrited above, the `Apache` gonna answer `index.html` file. such for `js` folder/files

What can I do for Rewrite all Requests to `index.html` BUT existing files/folders like `favicon.ico` or `Bootstrap` `css`/`js` files or pictures or `css`/`js` files in same folders?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35771013/htaccess-for-routing-single-page-applications

Answer (score 0):

As I read the first comment of the question ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/133915524?noredirect=1)), I understood that I can use this expression of `RewriteCond` (Conditioning before Rewriting)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . ./index.html
```

There are two condtions before rewriting all requests to `index.html` file, cheking `REQUEST_FILENAME` that makes sure that `REQUEST_FILENAME` is not (`!`) a file (`-f`) or directory (`-d`) in the current folder or in one of the subfolders of current folder

**Note:** Every `RewriteCond` before **ONE** `RewriteRule` only effects the same `RewriteRule` and does NOT effect any `RewriteRule` after that `RewriteRule`

Comment: With this you would need to make sure that `DirectoryIndex index.html` is also set (it _usually_ is by default) otherwise requests to the root directory itself are not rewritten to `index.html`. And `./index.html` should be simply `index.html` (the `./` eventually gets parsed away). However, if your statics assets are in a known set of subdirectories (as would seem to be implied in the question), then it would be more efficient to exclude these subdirectories, rather than perform filesystem checks on every request.

Comment: as you know I need to access my files!

Comment: and I didn't understand what did you say...